# From list to tuple

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, list-comprehension, python-3.6

I am trying to improve this [code](https://tentacles666.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/python-creating-a-sqlite3-database-from-csv-files/) to make it more efficient in Python 3.6.

`row` is a list (it comes from the `csv` reader)

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE %s (%s)" % (tablename,", ".join([ "%s text" % column for column in row ]))
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to go but so far I was able to improve the code by replacing the first two `%s` but not the third one.

```
query = 'CREATE TABLE  {0} ({1})'
sql = query.format(tablename, ", ".join([ "%s text" % column for column in row ]))
```

Is it possible to replace the third `%s`? Is using format the best way to go?

Comment: you mean `"{} text".format(column) for column in row` ?

Comment: It is *extremely* unlikely that this is a significant inefficiency for your program.

Comment: I doubt if string formatting will be your bottleneck in such a case.
If you want to improve performance, look into `multiprocessing` or search for `async` sql client

Comment: and with 3.6 you can do `f"{column}"` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE {0} ({1})".format(tablename,
                                      ','.join(["{} text".format(column) for column in row])
```

Mostly it's a question of personal preference. I, for one, always prefer to use `format` over c-style formatting syntax.

Answer (score 0):

not sure it's much faster but using `map` in `join` is possible here, which avoids the list comprehension and doesn't require a `lambda` either:

```
", ".join(map("{} text".format,row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE %s (%s text)" % (tablename, " text, ".join(row))
```

*Note:* `text` is needed for the last column name.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using Python 3.6 so you can use the [3.6 f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (they work like `format`) to make it faster <sup>1</sup> and shorter.

For your example:

```
columns = ", ".join([f"{column} text" for column in row])
query = f'CREATE TABLE {tablename} ({columns})'
```

Note that this way of making SQL queries makes you vulnerable to [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You probably should use prepared statements instead of formatting to create queries.

---

<sup>1</sup> They are faster than `%` or `format` but it's unlikely that it will significantly speed your program up. Normally string formatting isn't the bottleneck.